# Flutter + Revenue Cat | The device or user is not allowed to make the purchase

Tags: android, flutter, exception, payment

**Context**

Flutter base app with Revenue Cat support for store in-app items payments. Developed for Android and iOS. Currently in beta access on Play Store for mainly use in Singapore area.

**Problem**

When a user attempts to buy a one-time in-app item on Android devices. We catch the following exception.

````
PlatformException(3, The device or user is not allowed to make the purchase., {code: 3,
message: The device or user is not allowed to make the purchase., readableErrorCode:
PurchaseNotAllowedError, readable_error_code: PurchaseNotAllowedError,
underlyingErrorMessage: Error updating purchases. DebugMessage: . ErrorCode: 3.,
userCancelled: false}, null)```
````

Although we have our in-app item active in Play Store Console, Ids are synced between Play Store and Revenue Cat, our Play Store profile is set to receive payments, and, we already had payments succeed before.
On iOS we have no issues on this matter. Every purchase completes normally.

Example of a refused payment :
[refused payment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FTBL.png)

Based on our search, and after a response from Google support.
Everything points to an error with the payment methods/user profile (not logged into Google account).

But we have A LOT, AND ONLY refused payments in the last month.

Does anyone have the same issue?
Does the app need to be published to the store to avoid those errors? Is there something up with the Play Store Profile configuration which isn't explicitly shown?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: anyone found solution for this?

Comment: I have the same problem with an app which is already in production. So bad the error happens only in my customers devices, not in mine. Also, not every customer sees this error, because I have making some sales from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

I see this also sporadically. I may come from the version of Play Store, you can try to update it.
https://github.com/RevenueCat/purchases-flutter/issues/727